# a word describing a result of procrastination

Tags: word-usage, word-request

What's the noun in English to describe a situation, in which you need to urgently do a big amount of tasks that you would've had no problem completing on time had you not been procrastinating on for a long time?

Can the word "backlog" fit in here? Or will it be a case of wrong usage?

I need a noun that would fit in such phrases like "____ with math" or "math _____ ".

Like below:

"Jerry, I am sorry I can't go golfing with you today. I have a **real _______ with my math**. I will have to spend the whole afternoon and evening on it and will probably be also burning through midnight."

"Jerry, I am sorry I can't go golfing with you today. I have a **math _______**. I will have to spend the whole afternoon and evening on it and will probably be also burning through midnight."

Comment: _Backlog_ would make sense if you must use a noun. You might say something like "I've left myself masses of work to do" or "I'm really behind on my math(s)". NB _Burning through midnight_ is not an idiom - it's _burning the midnight oil_ (going back to the days of oil lamps).

Comment: The word "backlog" is unnatural in the context of school, but it's grammatically correct and meaningful to have a "math **homework** backlog". Whatever you have the backlog of has to have a quantity, and there is no quantity of math, just assignments or homework.